# Phpunit. Тесты в один поток

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Возникла проблема с phpunit на symfony из-за их параллельного выполнения.
Точнее, при выполнении setUp выполнение падает с сообщение о слишком большом кол-ве подключений к БД ( PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections )
Как запустить в один поток кучу не связанных (не depends) тестов?
Гугление пока не помогло.

Comment: > Возникла проблема с тестами из-за их параллельного выполнения.

Первый признак, что они немного неправильные

> Как запустить в один поток кучу не связанных (не depends) тестов?

скорее всего надо найти в тестах аннотации `@runInSeparateProcess` и убрать их

Comment: Я не указывал эту аннотацию в тестах.

Comment: @zenith, хм, а с чего вы решили, что они у вас параллельно бегают?

Comment: @Etki Проапдейтил вопрос. Я предположил что это единственная причина для возникновения такой ошибки (Too many connections).  
Если я не прав, подскажите куда рыть?

Comment: @zenith, по умолчанию они одним потоком (процессом, если точнее, в php пока еще нет поддержки потоков out-of-the-box) исполняются вроде бы. Проверьте подключения на самом двигле БД, проверьте, что подключения закрываются, выложите конкретный кусок кода.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что соединение не закрывалось автоматически.

$entityManager->getConnection()->close();

Нашёл ответ тут

Comment: @zenith, по-хорошему БД в юнит-тестах вообще не должна участвовать (да и доктрина тоже): http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/database.html

Comment: Согласен с Etki, это уже больше похоже на функциональное тестирование. Но все равно плюс.